# An ever-changing riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

To find me, you must first find my pairs,
A swarm of creatures, skittering inside walls,
Torturing the old way, sometimes using a chair,
A powerful figure, there until its empire falls,
Or some activities, one might enjoy in their lair.

**Who am I?**

Hint:

> A connection between all these words is what you seek
>  Once found, you won't be able to fall to the riddle's trick

Hint 2:

> It seems the riddle is getting a lot of people stuck
>  Only four letters are needed, and maybe a sliver of luck

Hint 3:

> My pairs have the same letters as I do,
>  Just rearrange them, to find something new!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are:

> **STAR** - the trick here is that all four of the other lines clue four-letter words (Hint 2) that are anagrams of these same four letters (Hint 3). Moreover, this word and the four others concealed in the puzzle are the *only* five common words that can be formed from these letters (Hint 1).

*A swarm of creatures, skittering inside walls,*

> **RATS** are creatures found in walls.

*Torturing the old way, sometimes using a chair,*

> **TARS** - [tarring and feathering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarring_and_feathering) was a form of torture and punishment used in the past.

*A powerful figure, there until its empire falls,*

> **[TSAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar)** - the equivalent of an Emperor in the former Bulgarian, Serbian and Russian empires.

*Or some activities, one might enjoy in their lair.*

> **ARTS** (like drawing, painting, and other creative pastimes) might be enjoyed in your spare time (and spare room).

This leaves just...

> ...**STAR** as the only other common anagram of these four letters. We have found your 'pairs' (i.e. other words sharing the same letters) through their 'ever-changing' ordering, so now we have found you too!

Comment: Remarkable answer, expertly done!

Answer (score 1):

This is not my forté, but how about

> term

> pairs of words are terms. termites skitter inside walls, eating wood.

> powerful figure - might (from -mite)?

> also a fixed time which may dominate our lives until it 'falls'.

> also the end of a pregnancy that one of the mites (the queen) may enjoy?

> connection between words is a term...

Comment: Sadly incorrect, though I appreciate the attempt!